# Rest API for Azure devops calendar not working

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to get the calendar data in azure devops using the rest api below:

```
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{teamId}.{monthNumber}.{year}/Documents
```

I tried this and replaced with my information but getting this message:

```
{
   "$id":"1",
   "innerException":null,
   "message":"%error=\"16902\";%:The collection does not exist\r\n%error=\"16902\";%:The collection does not exist",
   "typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.WebApi.DocumentCollectionDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ExtensionManagement.WebApi",
   "typeKey":"DocumentCollectionDoesNotExistException",
   "errorCode":0,
   "eventId":3900
}
```

I just want the calendar events from azure devops.

Comment: What permissions does your user have? You must have project collection admin permissions to read arbitrary extension data without a special extension auth token. How are you passing the auth token to your calls?

Comment: I am using a get request, simply pasting the url in the browser. I am able to get the other things from odata queries, Could you please provide me the details about fetching this data.

Answer (score 0):

> Rest API for Azure devops calendar not working

You need make sure you have the correct the organisation name in the URL.

I have installed the extension [Team Calendar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.team-calendar&targetId=b2bf9ecf-25cc-486f-82cb-6111d79e2adc&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList), add a event for test.

Then I use the REST API to get the value:

```
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{teamId}.{monthNumber}.{year}/Documents
```

Replace the `{organisation}`, `{teamId}`, `{monthNumber}`, `{year}` with my actual values：

[image]

Comment: Could you please tell me if i am using the correct url 
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/TEST-COMPANY/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.12.21/Documents
I am not sure about the date that i am adding at the end of team_id

Comment: Just a quick edit , I also tried adding date like this 
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/XXX-XXX/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXX.12.2021/Documents

Comment: @DataDoctor, if you use the second API, what is the result? You could share the info in the question, just edit it.

Comment: I have tried them both but still I'm getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the date in the URL and then use it like this instead:

```
https://extmgmt.dev.azure.com/{organisation}/_apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/ms-devlabs/team-calendar/Data/Scopes/Default/Current/Collections/{teamId}/Documents
```

There seem to be a change of the API between different versions of the extension.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried that in postman using my PAT but i am getting 410 unauthorized. Can you try from your side and send me a screenshot and the process please.